# require/typed contract in racket fails

Tags: scheme, racket, typed-racket

I've tried looking at the docs but i can't find an example that i can use for my case. I need to import [break](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-1.html?q=*#break) from srfi/1.

Here's my attempt. The example works in #lang racket.

```
#lang typed/racket

(require/typed (only-in srfi/1 break)
               ;[break (All (T) (-> (-> T Boolean) (Listof T) (Listof T)))])
               ;[break (All (T) (-> (-> T Boolean) (Values (Listof T) (Listof T))))])
               [break (All (T) (-> (-> String (U False (Listof T))) (Listof T) (Listof T)))])

(define entity-types '("3DFACE"  "3DSOLID"  "ACAD_PROXY_ENTITY" "ARC" "ARCALIGNEDTEXT"  "ATTDEF"  "ATTRIB"  "BODY"  "CIRCLE" "DIMENSION" "ELLIPSE"  "HATCH" "IMAGE"  "INSERT"  "LEADER"  "LINE" "LWPOLYLINE" "MLINE"  "MTEXT"  "OLEFRAME"  "OLE2FRAME"  "POINT" "POLYLINE" "RAY"  "REGION"  "RTEXT"  "SEQEND"  "SHAPE"  "SOLID" "SPLINE" "TEXT"  "TOLERANCE"  "TRACE"  "VERTEX"  "VIEWPORT" "WIPEOUT" "XLINE"))
(define lst '("ENTITIES" "0" "LINE" "5" "BA1C" "330" "1F" "100" "AcDbEntity" "8" "0" "370" "0" "100" "AcDbLine" "10" "253.2926653556182" "20" "1478.621431186484" "30" "0.0" "11" "253.2876653556182" "21" "1478.621431186484" "31" "0.0" "0" "LINE" "5" "BA1D" "330" "1F" "100" "AcDbEntity" "8" "0" "370" "0" "100" "AcDbLine" "10" "253.2876653556182" "20" "1478.621431186484" "30" "0.0" "11" "253.2876653556182" "21" "1476.655431186484" "31" "0.0" "0" "LINE" "5" "BA1E" "330" "1F" "100" "AcDbEntity" "8" "0" "370" "0" "100" "AcDbLine" "10" "253.2926653556182" "20" "1476.655431186484" "30" "0.0" "11" "253.2876653556182" "21" "1476.655431186484" "31" "0.0" "0" "LINE" "5" "BA1F" "330" "1F" "100" "AcDbEntity" "8" "0" "370" "0" "100" "AcDbLine" "10" "253.2926653556182" "20" "1476.655431186484" "30" "0.0" "11"))

(break (lambda ([x : String]) (member x entity-types)) lst)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the type I would assign to `break`:

```
(require/typed
 (only-in srfi/1 break)
 [break (All [T] (-> (T -> Any) (Listof T) 
                     (Values (Listof T) (Listof T))))])
```

The predicate function can return anything. If it returns `#f`, it will be treated as falsy, and any other result will be treated as truthy. Furthermore, as soegaard mentioned, the `Values` type constructor is needed to indicate that `break` returns multiple values.

However, Racket actually includes a function very similar to `break`, but it's actually equivalent to `span`. The function itself is called [`splitf-at`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._splitf-at%29%29), and it's very easy to implement `break` in terms of that function rather than using `srfi/1`.

```
(: break (All [T] (-> (T -> Any) (Listof T) 
                      (Values (Listof T) (Listof T)))))
(define (break pred lst)
  (splitf-at lst (negate pred)))
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
(require/typed (only-in srfi/1 break)
               [break (All (T) (-> (-> T (U False (Listof T))) (Listof T) 
                                   (values (Listof T) (Listof T))))])
```

Note that `member` returns either `#f` or a list whose first element is the element searched for. Therefore the predicate in the example `(lambda ([x : String]) (member x entity-types))` has the type `(-> T (U False (Listof T)))`.

Finally `values` is needed to indicate that `break` returns multiple values.